# mysqli_connect failure when using environment variable to specify the password

Tags: php, mysqli

EDIT: Whoever flagged this question as 'already answered in another post' no it is not already answered in another post. Other posts refer to mysqli authentication errors in general, for which I already verified that I can connect manually, and has has nothing to do with my question about the environment variable triggering the condition.

---

using PHP 7.4.3, I am having a very strange issue and I can't seem to figure out why it is happening.

When trying to connect to a MYSQL database as follows:

```
// connection to MySQL database
$values['DB_HOSTNAME'] = getenv('DB_HOSTNAME'); // database host
$values['DB_PORT']     = getenv('DB_PORT'); // database port
$values['DB_NAME']     = getenv('DB_NAME'); // database name
$values['DB_USERNAME'] = getenv('DB_USERNAME'); // database user name
$values['DB_PASSWORD'] = getenv('DB_PASSWORD'); // database password
```

I get the following error:

```
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'db-user'@'192.168.10.52' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/init.php on line 62
```

- If I echo the environment variable on the host and copy and paste
  directly to the password line instead of using `getenv`, it works
  fine.
- If I create a brand new environment variable directly on the host and
  put the correct password in, and set my config to point to that it
  fails.

So it seems to be some strange issue where reading from env is messing with the password somehow?

Also, `getenv` seems to be interpreting (mostly)? correctly as it connecting to the correct host, using the correct name, port, etc.

It seems like `getenv` is doing something to affect the password, for some strange reason.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thank you

Comment: Make sure the environment variable doesn't have any extra whitespace. You can use `trim()` to remove surrounding whitespace.

Comment: There is no mystic in computers. When a database says the password is incorrect, then it is so. Also, a password is just a string. Whatever is allegedly "done" to password by getenv is measurable. You can always convert any string into hex representation in order to see any invisible character. You can also always experiment, by having two connection codes, one using a hardcoded password and one from getenv, and output their hex representation to compare. If they match then the error is in another credential

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, I will give this a try.

Comment: UPDATE: @Barmar's solution worked. Thank you,

Comment: Another update: while Barmar's solution worked great, the real cause of my issue was a bad Kubernetes secret because I forgot to add '-n' when I base64 encoded the secret, thus adding an extra whitespace on the end. So for anyone working with environment variables in a Kubernetes setup specifically, see the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067557/kubernetes-secrets-have-trailing-whitespace-in-environment-variables